# Using mouseover and mouseout in a element makes a hover blinking continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I am rendering two elements on a JSP page dynamically, with dynamic IDs. On mouse over of each element I am rendering a `div`, and on mouse out I am making the same `display` value `none`. The issue is when I hover on the `div`, the `div` is keeping on blinking. How can I solve this?

Example code:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div onmouseover="showblock(hoverdivid)" onmouseout="hideblock(hoverdivid)">india</div>
            <div class="hoverdiv" id="dynamicallygenerated">
                <li>a list of checkboxes with state names of the country hovered will be inserted using ajax</li>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div onmouseover="" onmouseout="">america</div>
            <div class="hoverdiv" id="dynamicallygenerated">
                <li>a list of checkboxes with state names of the country hovered will be inserted using ajax</li>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
var showblock;
var hideblock;
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    showblock = function (id) {

        $("#" + id).show();

    }
    hideblock = function (id) {

        $("#" + id).hide();

    }

});
</script>
```

Extending my question

i mentioned that am inserting checkboxes in the hover using ajax, in the same hover i have an add button which adds the values that i checked in the hover to some other div outside the table. i have two countries so two hovers with their cites so when i checked and click on add the values of two hovers to be displayed which are checked should display individually suggest me the approach to follow to solve the above requirement

Comment: where is javascript code ?

Comment: I can't fix the problem without seeing the code. But I'm guessing it's because when you set `display: none`, the element disappears, so your mouse is no longer over the element, and a `mouseout` event is triggered. Then the element appears, and a `mouseover` event is triggered. So it loops between those forever.

Comment: Maybe if you tried [`visibility: hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) instead of `display: none`, that would avoid firing the event.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane code updated

Comment: @TusharGupta code updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because when the `hoverdiv` is shown your mouse is on it thus the `mouseleave` event is triggered so the `hoverdiv` disappears and then your mouse is on the first `div` again so the `mouseenter` event is triggered so `hoverdiv` appears again.... and so on.. this causes the flickering

My best suggestion will be to nest the hoverdiv: (You'll have to tweak the css a bit)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div onmouseover="" onmouseout="">
                india
                <div class="hoverdiv"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div onmouseover="" onmouseout="">
                america
                <div class="hoverdiv"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When the `hoverdiv` is inside the other `div`, `mouseleave` will not be triggered when you hover the `hoverdiv`

Comment: thanks for reply and am bit confused with your statement when the mouse is on a div in which i have return mouseover event why mouseleave will trigger. sorry if the question is crazy am newbie to the UI part.

Comment: @user1927762 You have it set so that when `mouseover` fires on the `element`, the element gets `display: none`. This style causes the element to disappear. Before the element disappeared, the mouse was over the element. Now that the element is gone, the mouse is no longer over the element. Thus, the browser fires a `mouseleave` event.

Comment: You hover "india" then hoverdiv appears. (your mouse is on the hoverdiv now so mouseleave is triggered). after hoverdiv disappears your mouse is on "india" again so hoverdiv appears again.. this process happens many times fast

Answer (score 0):

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/FKacT/1

**HTML**

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="div">india</div>
            <div class="hoverdiv" id="dynamicallygenerated">
                <li>a list of checkboxes with state names of the country hovered will be inserted using ajax</li>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="div">america</div>
            <div class="hoverdiv" id="dynamicallygenerated">
                <li>a list of checkboxes with state names of the country hovered will be inserted using ajax</li>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**css**

```
td{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.div').hover(function () {
        x = $(this).css('width');
        $(this).parent().find('.hoverdiv').show();
        $(this).css('width', $(this).parent('td').width());
    }, function () {
        $(this).css('width', x);
        $(this).parent().find('.hoverdiv').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: oh you mean i have to do opposite ?

Comment: @TusharGupta thanks for reply its clear now extension to my question i mentioned that am inserting checkboxes in the hover using ajax, in the same hover i have an add button which adds the values that i checked in the hover to some other div outside the table. i have two countries so two hovers with their cites so when i checked and click on add the values of two hovers to be displayed which are checked should display individually suggest me the approach to follow to solve the above requirement

Comment: @YotamOmer can you please look over my above comment